# bootstrap - align multiple buttons with large textbox using full container space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have a textbox in bootstrap, which has the same look and feel as the one you place inside a panel (large, rounded corners, full div length). On the right side of  such a textbox I want to have a few buttons.

I tried a bunch of stuff - either it becomes correctly aligned, but the textbox loses all styles. Or the textbox looks correct, but the buttons wrap down to next line!

Some of what I have tried:

```
<div class="row">
<div class='col-md-8'>  
  <input type="text" class="input-block-level input-lg" placeholder="Stuff 2">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
```

and...

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Stuff 2">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

and...

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="text"/>
    <button class="btn">Sign up</button>
</div>
```

Nothing works!I am thinking it shouldnt be so hard to place a bunch buttons next to a textbox that takes all available space and is nice and large :(

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: One thing I do when sussing out Bootstrap style tweaks: first make sure you can accomplish the changes using naked CSS/Sass/LESS. *Then* figure out how to do it "the Bootstrap way" which is not always the 100% correct or "semantic" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do it like this?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Stuff2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh my..oh my..oh my - sometimes we can't see the forest because of the trees!! That works, and I was like.. *facepalm* ..when I saw how you did it, thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: No worries. Sometimes it's the little things that drive you nuts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that to combine textbox and button, I use:

```
class="input-group"
```

and give `class="form-control"` to all textboxes

You mean like this follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-8'> 
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Stuff 2">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Delete</button>
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Stuff 2">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn">Sign up</button>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

If it is what you mean, here's the demo:
[**Demo in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/hpjus357/)

Comment: Thanks for that example, however I do not want them in that "bootstrap style", if you understand me. I just want textbox,space,button,space,button... Like how we normally place them in regular HTML